# Please someone explain me, what is the purpose of the loop (with its wait()) in Line B?

Tags: fork, wait

What is the meaning of line B? I am forking the process 10 times,
displaying the process IDs, then calling `wait()` 10 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Fork the process 10 times
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  // Catch the PID
  if (pid = fork() < 0)
    // error
  else if (pid == 0) {

  function_A();

  return 0;
}

  printf(“process ID: %d \n”, pid); // Line A

}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Line B

wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` kicks of child processes asynchronously. Meaning, they start, and get thrown to the background.

`wait()` tells the computer to "wait" for them to end.

So, it's telling the parent process to wait for child processes to end before continuing execution.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wait-system-call-c/